How to add face/ fill edges to inner geometry in geometry nodes?
I have generated a randomized floor effect in geometry nodes, but some values give an empty face in the middle. To fix it, I thought of converting it to a curve and using a "fill curve" node before converting it back to a mesh, but it does not work, and it gives weird triangles on the edges. I want to get rid of the empty spaces in the middle, since it won't make sense for the floor plans I want to create.






Please do not take photos of your monitor, make proper screenshots.

About Gordon comment: use the main menu entry Window>Save Screenshot (Editor). (see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/topbar.html#window-menu)

Spawn another grid aligned with what you currently have and delete edges based on proximity to edges on your grid.

Sorry @Gordon Brinkmann, I did not know. StefLAncien, thank you for the tip, I did not know there was this feature in blender. Markus von Broady, that solution might work if I was working with one static mesh, but since the mesh changes with every randomized seed, it won't work when the seed is changed.

Ok.... so, what is the final purpose of this? If you fill the gaps, won't it be just a normal grid?

I misunderstood earlier screenshots (photos), I thought you actually want to keep some holes. The solution is to not immediately delete faces, instead mark for deletion, select non-deleted, separate, extrude boundary edges, than use that for raycasting to detect which faces marked for deletion are inside the boundary (and therefore shouldn't be deleted).

@Daniel Moller, I only want to delete the faces around the grid not inside. If I were to make a house with this, there would be a random hole that most modern houses (if any, except a courtyard, which I do not want) do not have. It won't be a grid, because the faces surrounding the edges would still be deleted.

@Markus von Broady I am not completely sure on how that process would go (like which node to use, and which ones it connects to). Which node to use to mark for deletion, selecting non deleted, and extruding the boundry edges? I am guessing for seperation, I would need, "separate geometry" right?

So, what about deleting only "border" faces? This sounds like an answer unless you explain your goal better:


Delete faces with a random probability, provided that their neighbor count is less than 4 (which means they're not in the middle of the grid)
Delete spurious faces that may be left at the corners without any neighbor


This answer is exactly what I was looking for. I did the node group of deleting faces with random probability twice (I duplicated it), instead of once with a lower probability the second time, before deleting spurious faces without any neighbors (I had to change it to less than or equal to 1 instead of equal to 0, after repeating the 1st step twice). Now it looks really similar to how a base floor plan would look like. Thank you for the help!

@JessieFerret, cool. You could try to use the "equal 0" twice. The difference is having the probability of creating L shaped sections, while when you do "less or equal 1" you remove the Ls

Using the less or equal 1 does give less Ls and less random faces that stick out. The reason I did so though was when I put the probability to less than 0.4, some seeds randomly give faces that float alone with no connected faces. So either I put them both as equal to 0 and put the probability over 0.5 or put one as equal to zero and the other equal to 1 while bringing the probability lower than 0.4.
